# How can I set cookies on both secure and non-secure origins at the same time?

Tags: ajax, cookies, https

I have a front-end login process via `admin-ajax.php`. It's a standard user/pass form so I submit the POST request to a secure, https, endpoint regardless of whether the user is currently on a secure connection. The user is thus logged in on the secure domain - but WordPress does not recognize the login on the insecure domain she may be browsing from. How can I set cookies on both secure and non-secure origins at the same time? I've been exploring something like hooking into the `set_logged_in_cookie` action but can't get both sets of cookies to stick.

Related but unanswered questions: [How can I make an Ajax login form work with FORCE_SSL_ADMIN enabled?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2337/how-can-i-make-an-ajax-login-form-work-with-force-ssl-admin-enabled) and [AJAX-login over https on a http page, is it possible?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140534/ajax-login-over-https-on-a-http-page-is-it-possible?lq=1)

Comment: The first question actually have several answers most of them are good, so why neither of them apply to you?

Comment: @MarkKaplun because they are answers to a different question. I'm trying to set cookies on both secure and insecure at the same time, not one or the other.

Comment: Yes, you do want to do something insecure and wordpress do not make it easier ;) sounds like your design is lacking, either you have authentication cookies on http or you have security, you can not have both

Comment: @MarkKaplun I'm not following. Thousands and thousands of websites login users over https from http pages. This is in fact much more secure than using http straight up.

Comment: but once you are logged in, you are served only https and therefor do not need the http auth cookie.

Comment: on http maybe you just need a cookie that says that the user is logged in so you will know you need to go https, but nothing more then that